# Db Connection simple file, cant remember the extension

Tags: sql-server, database, windows

I used to create a .txt file and rename it to something. Then when you opened it it displays the connection wizard that you would normally see in visual studio for connecting to a db.

It was soo handy for generating correct connection strings but I've forgotten what the three letter extension was now.

Anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `.UDL` (Microsoft Data Link) File.

Answer (score 1):

change your file extention to a.udl